# @IgnoredOnParcel annotation doesn't work for @Parcelize in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, parcelable

I try to ignore a field when using the @Parcelize annotation in Kotlin so I am using @IgnoredOnParcel,

Plz guide me, on how to solve this error

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private final com.boltuix.mvvm.model.Source source = null;
                 ^
```

**Here is my full source code:**
https://github.com/BoltUIX/REST-APIs-with-Retrofit-and-MVVM-architecture.

[image: How to ignore fields when using @Parcelize annotation in Kotlin]

Now i have a plan to recreate the data class, **is there any better solution to ignore fields**

```
@Entity(tableName = "favorite_movie")
@Parcelize
data class Article(
    val author: String?,
    val content: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val publishedAt: String?,
    val pagedLists: Source,
    val title: String?,
    val url: String?,
    val urlToImage: String?
): Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id : Int = 0

    @IgnoredOnParcel
    var pagedList: Source = pagedLists

}
```

@IgnoredOnParcel annotation doesn't work for @Parcelize  in Kotlin

.............................
To ignore for Room, then you need to use Room's **@Ignore** annotation is not working for me

```
error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
public final class Article implements android.os.Parcelable {..



@Entity(tableName = "favorite_movie")
@Parcelize
data class Article(
    val author: String?,
    val content: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val publishedAt: String?,
    @Ignore val pagedLists: Source,
    val title: String?,
    val url: String?,
    val urlToImage: String?
): Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id : Int = 0

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To ignore for Room, then you need to use Room's **`@Ignore`** annotation. It will then ignore the field as being a column and thus does not need to know how to save the field.

re

> error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
> public final class Article implements android.os.Parcelable {..

Room, if using `@Ignore`, does not know about the `pagedLists` and therefore MUST have a way to construct an Article without supplying the `pagedLists` value (as it doesn't have a value or the `pagedLists` field).

e.g. you could have something like :-

```
constructor(author: String?, content: String?, description: String?, publishedAt: String?, title: String?, url: String?, urlToImage: String?)
            : this(author = author, content = content,description =description, publishedAt = publishedAt, title = title, url = url, urlToImage = urlToImage, pagedLists = Source())
```

- This assumes that you can construct the Source with no parameters (either `?`'s or default values)

The alternative would be to have two classes on according to Room's columns, the other extending/embedding the first (without the pagedLists field) class.

Comment: i tried to @ignore annotation , but it is not working,